# Error for remove mysql-server-8.0 on linux system

Tags: linux, php, mysql, mariadb

Hello my mysql install is broken i can't uninstall or reinstall them i'm stuck.

> Os: POP Os 20.04 LTS

> Mysql: mysql  Ver 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

> Problem
>
> > I have installed mysql properly and started to using them in local env, but if i wanted to connect me to mysql with this command: `mysql -u root -p` i have the error: `cant connect with 'root'@'localhost'`, if i use `sudo mysql -u root -p` everything work.
> > If i will use mysql in laravel for push migration i need to use `sudo php artisan migrate` instead of `php artisan migrate` i have follow these link for try to fix my problem [stackoverflow.com/a/38722661/4575350](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38722661/4575350) and [stackoverflow.com/a/15039113/4575350](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15039113/4575350) nothing work for me i had every time the same error if i will remove mysql installation:

```sh
user@pc-master : sudo apt remove mysql-server-8.0

Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Les paquets suivants seront ENLEVÉS :
  mysql-server mysql-server-8.0
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 2 à enlever et 0 non mis à jour.
2 partiellement installés ou enlevés.
Après cette opération, 1 565 ko d'espace disque seront libérés.
Souhaitez-vous continuer ? [O/n] o
(Lecture de la base de données... 241161 fichiers et répertoires déjà installés.)
Suppression de mysql-server (8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4) ...

Progression : [  0%] [................................................................................................................................................................] 
Progression : [ 25%] [########################################........................................................................................................................] 
Suppression de mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4) ...#########################################................................................................................] 
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet mysql-server-8.0 (--remove) :
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trop d'erreurs, arrêt
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
Failed to preset unit: File mysql.service: Link has been severed
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: systemctl preset failed on mysql.service: No such file or directory
Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
Unit mysql.service could not be found.
dpkg : error while cleaning up:
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 mysql-server-8.0
L'exécution a été arrêtée car il y avait trop d'erreurs.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Step that i follow to got this error:

- install mysql : `sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client`
- install php extension: `sudo apt install php-pdo php-mysql`

after that i have the bug so i use these command:

- remove mysql: `sudo apt remove mysql-server-8.0 mysql-client`
- purge mysql: `sudo apt purge mysql-server-8.0 mysql-client`
- autoremove unused dependencies: `sudo apt autoremove`, `sudo apt clean`
- also i have try with: `dpkg -r mysql-client`, `mysql-server-8.0`

Every command that i do, does not work i had the same error:

```sh
dpkg : error while cleaning up:
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 mysql-server-8.0
L'exécution a été arrêtée car il y avait trop d'erreurs.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Previously use mysql i have install `mariadb-server` and `mariadb-client` same problem for root user, but mariadb has been removed properly

I have delete `/etc/mysql` folder and `/var/lib/mysql` i deleted these folder to fix my issue but i think this add me another issue , i have the `/usr/bin/mysql`

Comment: MariaDB and MySql are not the same thing (as I am guessing that you already know).  Those code bases split a LONG time ago.  Why would you choose to use MySQL over MariaDB?  I have never had anything but nightmares with MySQL installations.. I guess you are seeing one here.

Comment: hello yes i that i fix the problem with this command: `find broken package with: dpkg --configure -a` and `dpkg -P --force-all 'broken-package`

Comment: You should post your own answer.  It looks like not only will it help the next person, you could use the points :)

Comment: Yes ! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

i fix the problem with these command:

> find broken package with:
> `dpkg --configure -a`

and

`dpkg -P --force-all 'broken-package-to uninstall`

Comment: See! 8-) some points!

Comment: Thank you bro :)

Comment: Wait two days, then accept your own answer and get even more.  Many people make up stupid things to do this.. but this one is legit.

Comment: Ho really ? ok i will remind me this :)